# Leiningen nREPL connect to remote repl with drawbridge

Tags: clojure, leiningen, nrepl

I'm trying to connect to a running clojure app package as a uberjar. I added `[com.cemerick/drawbridge "0.0.7"]` to my project.clj. But when I trying to connect with `lein repl :connect http://ip:port/repl` it is like it is not even connecting.

I get a stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cemerick/drawbridge/client__init.class or cemerick/drawbridge/client.clj on classpath.
at clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:456)
clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:419)
clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke (core.clj:5893)
clojure.core$load.invokeStatic (core.clj:5892)
clojure.core$load.doInvoke (core.clj:5876)
....
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:171)
clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
```

But when I run `lein classpath` I can find drawbridge there `/root/.m2/repository/com/cemerick/drawbridge/0.0.7/drawbridge-0.0.7.jar`

```
jar tf /root/.m2/repository/com/cemerick/drawbridge/0.0.7/drawbridge-0.0.7.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/com.cemerick/drawbridge/pom.xml
...
cemerick/drawbridge/client.clj
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a plain old regression in [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). I have submitted this as https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2370.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the same command on a older lein (clojure:lein-2.7.1) and it looks better. Something is maybe wrong on the server side but it connect at least.

Answer (score 0):

Leiningen [does not include Drawbridge anymore](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2370) and you need to add it explicitly to plugins:

```clj
(defproject whatever "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :plugins [[nrepl/drawbridge "0.2.1"]]))
```

See [nREPL over HTTP(s) with Drawbridge in 2020](https://blog.jakubholy.net/nrepl-over-http-with-drwabridge-in-2020/)